# Google forms automation fill out

Tags: javascript, automation, google-forms, autofill

This is my google form to be filled as survey but i have not got time to go out and do it, So i need some automated dummy fill outs for my submission.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vnbi.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJLtq.jpg)

I tried attaching it with chat gpt but couldn't do it, anybody please help this is due.

Answer (score 0):

you could do keyword driven framework with dynamic excel data entering, Everytime form will be filled with any new data for daily basis

Your image is not opening

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).